# Microsoft Identity Delegated and Application Permissions in same API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I've been working with some of the ASP.NET core examples for APIs secured using Microsoft Identity. One scenario I haven't been able to find an example for is when you have a protected API that needs to make requests to another API (Microsoft Graph, one of my own APIs, etc) with delegated AND application permissions.

For example, say I want to update a user's profile on behalf of the user (delegated), but then I want the application to update their manager's profile using the application permissions (on behalf of the application's identity). Is there an example of this scenario? Would the application that's making the API calls request two tokens?

Comment: For the Microsoft Identity Delegated, it looks that you want to use Microsoft Graph, but for the Application permissions, can you explain more detail about that, use JWT authentication? Do you mean you want to configure the same API with two kinds of authentication methods (JWT + AAD), use each of them can access the API method and update the user's profile? If that is the case, it is hard to find the existing example, which is totally achieved your requirement, you can search them one by one, and then create an application and implement them together.

Comment: That's correct, I'd want to call Graph within the context of the user AND as the application context, but from what I'm starting to understand is that's against the conventions of Microsoft Identity / OpenID. Instead everything should be delegated as the current user, and the application shouldn't do anything that the user doesn't have authentication do to?